# getting all the url's to an arraylist from firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage, uri, android-glide

i'm trying to get all the urls of a specific folder to an arraylist of urls, and then update them all into a grid view.

this is the code i tried

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
    StorageReference storageReference=storage.getReference().child(groupCode);
    

    storageReference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
           for(StorageReference fileRef:listResult.getItems()){
               fileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                       galleryArrayList.add(new PictureClass(uri));
                       Log.d("item", uri.toString());
                   }
               }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                       adaptor=new ImageAdaptor(requireContext(),galleryArrayList);

                   }
               });
           }
       }
   });
   gridView.setAdapter(adaptor);
}
```

however it has collapsed

i also know there are libaries such as glide and picasso, however i dont know how to work with them and i dont want to change ,my image adaptor. what can i do?